# A word for a person who gets bored easily with something after actively seeking it

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any word available for a person who gets bored easily with something they liked? May be a guy who wishes for expensive stuff but once received he finds it rather monotonous!!

Example:

> Chris bought that watch for $200, however he is not using it, he is
>   such a ______ person.

Comment: Your question suggests that you are looking for a noun which indicates a specific type of person. Your example sentence suggests you are looking for a word to describe a state of mind. Which are you looking for?

Comment: I modified the question in accordance with ur comment.

Comment: "Chris bought that watch for 200$, however he is not using it, he is such a (monotonous) person".

Answer (score 4):

Noncommittal : Not expressing or revealing commitment to a definite opinion or course of action.

He did not go through with his course of action in buying the watch.

Flighty: Fickle and irresponsible.

He was irresponsible for wasting money.

Capricious: Given to sudden and unaccountable changes of mood or behaviour.

Changing his mind about the watch was an unaccountable change of behavior.

Whimsical could also work. Similar meaning to capricious.

Comment: All good options... but I'd add "flibbertigibbet".

Comment: Is flibbertigibbet ever used outside of The Sound of Music?

Answer (score 4):

> Chris bought that watch for $200, however he is not using it, he is
> such a ***fickle*** person.

ODO:

> **[fickle](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/fickle)**
>
> *ADJECTIVE*
>
> Changing frequently, especially as regards one's loyalties, interests,
> or affection.
>
> ‘Unlike Fred who is a creature of habit, I am far more fickle, always
> in need of new experiences, change and variety.’

Collins:

> **[fickle](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fickle)**
>
> *adjective*
>
> If you describe someone as fickle, you disapprove of them because
> they keep changing their mind about what they like or want.

Answer (score 0):

> Chris bought that watch for $200, however he is not using it, he is
> such an **inconstant** person.

## inconstant

> 1. Frequently changing; variable or irregular.
> 2. (of a person or their behavior) not faithful and dependable.

([ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/inconstant))

Answer (score 0):

Insatiable seems like the right word as it describes somebody who is never able to be satisfied

Comment: I encourage you to [edit] this with more information (it was flagged probably for length), but it's the start of an answer that could really work.  Please take the [tour], and welcome to EL&U.